# shell find -delete -- how to avoid delete itself

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
root
  -- level-1-folder-1-dynamic
  -- level-1-folder-2-dynamic-maybe-empty
  -- level-1-folder-3-dynamic
     -- level-2-folder-dynamic-need-to-be-deleted
     -- level-2-folder-dynamic-need-to-be-deleted
        -- file-1
        -- file-2
```

I want to use `find command` to delete all level-2-folders that created 30mins before, but I can't find all level-2 folders and delete them.
What I can do now is to find all the files and delete them, but the level-2-folders still remain
`find root -type -f -cmin +30 -delete`
And if I using `find root -type -d -empty -delete`, it will delete all the empty folders, including level-1 and root itself.

How can I delete all the level-2-folders?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To delete only those empty directories that are level 2 or deeper, use `-mindepth 2`:

```
find root -mindepth 2 -type d -empty -delete
```

Comment: great. Although I've tried `-mindepth 2`, but I'm not sure why I failed...Thanks

Comment: First, run `find root -mindepth 2 -type d -empty` (without the delete option) and see if it gives you the list of directories that you expect.

Comment: thanks, but one other thing is the `-delete` not working on 'not empty' folder, I can't delete it if the level-2-folder has files in it

Comment: @Awakening Easy enough: if you want to delete all folders, empty or not, at level 2, then simply use: `find root -mindepth 2  -delete`

Comment: Wonderful!Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

> to delete all level-2-folders that <strike>created 30mins before</strike>

```
ssam@udistro:~/so/36928504$ tree root
```

gives me

```
root
|-- level1
|   |-- level2dir1
|   |-- level2dir2
|   |   `-- level2dir2file1
|   `-- level2file
`-- level1emptydir
```

I did :

```
find root -mindepth 2 -type d 2>/dev/null -exec rm -fR {} \;
```

The doing :

```
ssam@udistro:~/so/36928504$ tree root
```

gives me :

```
root
|-- level1
|   `-- level2file
`-- level1emptydir
```

which is what you want I guess..

Comment: hei, thanks for you answer. There has two things: 1. /your/path, the path is level-1-folder, and it is also dynamic. 2. -not -name file, how about level-2-folder also named 'root' , then it will not be deleted ?

Comment: the root's sub-folder is level-1-folder-dynamic, and sub-folder's sub is level-2-folder-dynamic, and what I want to delete is all level-2-folder-dynamic

Comment: @Awakening : I have made an edit since the last comment. Can you check from my output hierarchy pls? Here level2file is just a file which got spared & `level1` and `level1emptydir` are level1 directories